# Hypothesis Testing of Two Binomial Proportions, can't understand a simple textbook example

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

I saw this question in Sheldon Ross's Introduction to Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists P.335, [Google Link](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=BaPOv33uZCMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Introduction+to+Probability+and+Statistics+for+Engineers+and+Scientists&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBvPz-o9LqAhUdy4sBHZOaBdsQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=example%208.6e&f=false)

> Suppose that method 1 resulted in 20 unacceptable transistors out of 100 produced, wheras method 2 resulted in 12 unacceptable transistors out of 100 produced. Can we conclude from this, at the 10% significance level, that the two methods are equivalent?

It simply says that p-value is 0.1763 and so H<sub>0</sub> is not rejected without showing any calculations.

I don't understand why the p-value is so different. Can you let me know where I made the mistake?

```
#Octave calculator
pkg load statistics;
x1 = 20; #method 1 number
n1 = 100; #method 1 sample size
p1 = x1 / n1; #method 1 proportion
x2 = 12; #method 2 number
n2 = 100; #method 2 sample size
p2 = x2 / n2; #method 2 proportion
p = (x1 + x2) / (n1 + n2); #pooled proportion
sd = sqrt( p*(1-p)*(1/n1 + 1/n2) ); #standard error
zscore = (p1 - p2)/sd ; #test statistics
p = 1 - normcdf(zscore, 0, 1) ; #p = 0.0614 > 0.05, so not rejected
#p-value * 2 for 2-sided test, so 0.123 in a 10%-level test
#textbook says p-value = 0.1763, a very large difference.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the paragraph above your example, it seems that Program 8.6.1 implements the Fisher-Irwin test for the equality of two Bernoulli probabilities. You are using an asymptotic two sample proportion test, rather than Fisher's exact test:

```
 . prtesti 100 20 100 12, count

Two-sample test of proportions                     x: Number of obs =      100
                                                   y: Number of obs =      100
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |       Mean   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |         .2        .04                      .1216014    .2783986
           y |        .12   .0324962                      .0563087    .1836913
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        diff |        .08   .0515364                     -.0210095    .1810095
             |  under Ho:   .0518459     1.54   0.123
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        diff = prop(x) - prop(y)                                  z =   1.5430
    Ho: diff = 0

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(Z < z) = 0.9386         Pr(|Z| > |z|) = 0.1228          Pr(Z > z) = 0.0614

. tabi 80 20 \ 88 12 , exact

           |          col
       row |         1          2 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 |        80         20 |       100 
         2 |        88         12 |       100 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |       168         32 |       200 

           Fisher's exact =                 0.176
   1-sided Fisher's exact =                 0.088
```

With a smaller sample, this can make a difference.

Comment: Interesting to see result of Fisher exact test here (+1). However, the asymptotic test of two proportions is not really an 'approximation' of the result of Fisher's exact test. The tests differ in assumptions, in ways that have been debated almost since Fisher proposed his test. (Fisher's presentations often evoked controversy.)

Comment: @BruceET Yes, you are correct. I was sloppy.

Comment: Before, slightly, but right on target now.

Comment: I don't understand why Mr. Ross introduced that Fisher test there, and rather lightly in less than a page. Most other texts I read all talk about using Z in 'large' sample using a pooled proportion for H0: p1 = p2

Comment: @ABCAnalytics I don't know. My guess it that engineers prefer exact tests for small samples. My dad was was a metallurgical engineer in the Soviet Union and I work in tech in California. My sample size for a single test probably exceed what he sampled/experimented on over his whole career.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems that the P-value in your text might have
come from the `prop.test` procedure in R:

```
prop.test(c(20,12),c(100,100))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(20, 12) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 1.8229, df = 1, p-value = 0.177
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03100948  0.19100948
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.20   0.12
```

The use of the Yates continuity correction has been
deprecated, especially for samples as large as 100.

If we use the parameter `cor=F` in `prop.test` then
we get P-value is $0.1228 \approx 12.3\%.$

```
prop.test(c(20,12),c(100,100), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(20, 12) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 2.381, df = 1, p-value = 0.1228
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.02100948  0.18100948
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.20   0.12
```

Second, your P-value $0.0614$ is for a one-sided test and the output from `prop.test` is for a 2-sided test.
Doubling your P-value, we get $0.1228,$ which agrees with
the output from R.

Finally, neither the P-value 0.12 nor the P-value 0.17 would reject the null hypothesis that that the two methods are equivalent at the 10% level.
That does not mean that the two methods are exactly equivalent, only that we do not have evidence in the data provided to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: +1. In further support of your rejection of the continuity correction, a simulation of a million (x,y) pairs from $H_0:p=(20+12)/(100+100)$ gives a p-value of $0.129.$